# Fechas en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Tengo que imprimir todos los años en que el 1 de Enero caiga en Domingo desde el año actual hasta el 2080. ¿Cómo se podría hacer?.

Ejemplo: En estos años el 1 de Enero es Domingo : 2020,2025,2030...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facil.

```js
for (i=2018; i <= 2080; i++) {
    var date = new Date('1/1/'+i);
    if(date.getDay() == 0) console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: Hola Alan. A parte de lo que te dije ayer de repsonder preguntas de baja calidad (ya se que esta respuesta es de antes de que te lo dijera ) has de explicar mejor las respuestas. No solo poner "facil" ya que obviamente para el que pregunta no lo es. Explica cómo funciona tu respuesta, por ejemplo el `getDay` . Un saludo